# Blackberry Screen navigation from MenuItem

Tags: java, user-interface, blackberry, navigation, menuitem

Would the code below cause an issue if it was called from the run method of a MenuItem?
My concern is whether the MenuItem is part of the UiEvent thread and if there could be some side effects.

```
  //Allow back and forward navigation 
  void openScreen(eSafeScreen nextScreen) {
      //remains on current screen if next screen does not exists
      if (nextScreen != null) { 
          nextScreen._prevScreen = this;
          UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(nextScreen);
          UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(this);
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, MenuItem is a part of UI thread.
No, it's not the case you should worry about UI thread.

See also: [Thinking Blackberry - BlackBerry UI Threading - The Very Basics](http://thinkingblackberry.com/?p=182)